# Why is my GoogleServiceInfo.plist file missing CLIENT_ID and REVERSED_CLIENT_ID?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sdk

I cannot understand why whenever I add an iOS app to my firebase project, my plist file comes without these fields,CLIENT_ID and REVERSED_CLIENT_ID, which are both important for Auth and Messaging. Anyone struck with the same problem before?

I have tried everything from creating a new project, to adding and removing apps from the project, and nothing.

Comment: Has Auth been configured in the project before downloading the GoogleService-Info.plist?

Comment: No it hasn't, should it be? @PaulBeusterien

Answer (score 6):

I was getting similar Issue. After Around April 2023 . When We Created New Project on Firebase for some reason(IDK) firebase doesn't automatically generates the Client_Id and Reserved_Client_Id. I was only using phone authentication for my Project. Later When I Enable Google Sign In and Download .plist file. Reserved and Client Id showed UP. I Hope This Helps you.

If it doesn't try enabling OAuth2.0 from GoogleCloud(I don't know if it works or not i found it. )

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did not build "Authentication" in my Firebase project. After built it and configured providers, I could find the `CLIENT_ID` and `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Can not find **REVERSED_CLIEND_ID** in **GoogleService-Info** file.
All you need to add Google authentication into your firebase project.
follow below steps...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

after following all steps just download again your GoogleService-info file and delete old file.

**cheers happy coding**